# window.pageYOffset not giving expected value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page with 4 sections - section 1,2,3,4. On clicking each section I will scroll to the next section. On clicking the last section which is section 4 I will scroll back to the top i.e. section 1. All these functionalities are working fine. The challenge I am having here is when I am writing the scroll positions before and after click to the console log, I am getting the same start and end scroll positions for window.pageYOffset. I am unable to figure out why I am getting so. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Below is the link of the jsfiddle for your reference
https://jsfiddle.net/seshadri27/5np0v9rt/8/

```
    const sectionList = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

    const sectionHeight = Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(sectionList[0]).height);

    sectionList.forEach(function(section){

        section.addEventListener('click',function(e){

        console.log(`data count:${section.dataset.count}`);

        console.log(`Start scroll position X/Y: ${window.pageXOffset}/${window.pageYOffset}`)

        if (section.dataset.count == 4){

            scrollTo({top:0,
                      left:0,
                      behavior:'smooth'})
        }

        else{
            scrollTo({top:sectionHeight * section.dataset.count,
                      left:0,
                      behavior:'smooth'})
        }

        console.log(`End scroll position X/Y: ${window.pageXOffset}/${window.pageYOffset}`)

        })
    }
    )
```